# Get request headers using GAE Protocol RPC service method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

I am using [Google App Engine's Protocol RPC library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/). I want to get the headers for a request and check that a certain header exists. I can't figure out how to get the requests headers?

The code basically looks like this:

```
class MyService(remote.Service):
    @remote.method(MyRequest, MyResponse)
    def my_request(self, request):
        # TODO: Check that header exists in request
```

The passed in request object is of the type 'MyRequest' and doesn't have any header information attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special method [initialize_request_state](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/remote/) that allows you to access all of the requests headers.

```
class MyService(remote.Service):

    def initialize_request_state(self, state):
        self.headers = state.headers

    @remote.method(MyRequest, MyResponse)
    def my_request(self, request):
        logging.debug(self.headers)
```